# Convert column data in DataTable request into an array

Tags: javascript, express, datatables

This is for an Express.js version 4.18.2 web application.  The web app serves an HTML page that contains a `<table>`, and I use the DataTables jQuery plug-in to make the table more fancy.

## Client side

In the HTML page, the DataTable is configured to use server side processing, and the columns of the table are also defined.

```
<html>
<body>
  ...
  <table id="person_table">
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  ...

  <script>
    $( document ).ready( function ()
    {
      var config = {};

      // Define columns.
      var c = 0;
      config.columnDefs = [];
      config.columnDefs.push( { targets: c++, data: "name", name: "name" } );
      config.columnDefs.push( { targets: c++, data: "phone", name: "phone" } );

      // Server side processing mode.
      config.serverSide = true;

      // Load records from an Ajax source, i.e., the server.
      config.ajax =
      {
        // The URL to which the request is sent.
        url: '/person/load',

       // Send an HTTP post request.
       type: 'POST',
      };

      // Create the DataTable.
      $( '#person_table' ).DataTable( config );
    } );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Server side

When the web app receives a request from the DataTable to load records, the DataTable specific data is in the following format.

```
request: <ref *2> IncomingMessage {
  ...
  body: [Object: null prototype] {
    draw: '1',
    'columns[0][data]': 'name',
    'columns[0][name]': 'name',
    'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
    'columns[0][orderable]': 'true',
    'columns[0][search][value]': '',
    'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
    'columns[1][data]': 'phone',
    'columns[1][name]': 'phone',
    'columns[1][searchable]': 'true',
    'columns[1][orderable]': 'true',
    'columns[1][search][value]': '',
    'columns[1][search][regex]': 'false',
    'order[0][column]': '0',
    'order[0][dir]': 'asc',
    start: '0',
    length: '10',
    'search[value]': '',
    'search[regex]': 'false'
  },
  ...
}
```

The data about the columns in the table is "flat".  i.e., there are several "columns[i][property name]" entries instead of an array of objects containing column data.

I could go to the trouble to parse the column data myself and convert it into an array of objects.  However, https://datatables.net/manual/server-side says:

> In most modern server-side scripting environments this data [i.e., the
> order and column data] will automatically be available to you as an
> array.

## The question

Is there something in Express.js or Node.js that can automatically convert that column data into an array of objects for me?

Comment: The [jQuery serializeArray()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serializearray.asp) function seems like it might do what I want.  I wonder if I can use that function on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is to set the extended flag for the URL encoded body parser to true instead of false.

For example, in the main Javascript file for the Express web application:

```
const BodyParser = require( 'body-parser' );
const Express = require( 'express' );

const app = Express();

// It is important for the extended flag to be true,
// so that the array and object data in an HTTP request is not flattened. 
app.use( BodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: true } ) );

...
```

When the web app receives a request from the DataTable to load records, the DataTable specific data is now in a more useful format.

```
request: <ref *2> IncomingMessage {
  ...
  body: {
    draw: '1',
    columns: [
      {
        data: 'name',
        name: 'name',
        searchable: 'true',
        orderable: 'true',
        search: [Object]
      },
      {
        data: 'phone',
        name: 'phone',
        searchable: 'true',
        orderable: 'true',
        search: [Object]
      }
    ],
    order: [ { column: '0', dir: 'asc' } ],
    start: '0',
    length: '10',
    search: { value: '', regex: 'false' }
  },
  ...
}
```